# Python switch case

Tags: python, switch-statement

I am trying to use dictionary as switch case on python, however, the parameter does not seem to be pass to the called function, please help:

```
def switchcase(num,cc):
    def fa(num):
        out= num*1.1;
    def fb(num):
        out= num*2.2;
    def fc(num):
        out= num*3.3;
    def fd(num):
        out= num*4.4;
    options = {
        "a":fa(num),
        "b":fb(num),
        "c":fc(num),
        "d":fd(num)
        } 
    out=0
    options[cc];
    return out
print switchcase(10,"a")
```

the output is 0, I could not figure out the problem

Comment: You're not returning anything from your sub-functions.

Comment: The parameter `cc` *is* in fact being passed to the `switchcase` function, but where are you using it?

Comment: As a note of style (because someone will probably point it out someday), most python coders prefer to **not** terminate lines with semicolons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is:

```
out=0
options[cc];
return out
```

Basically -- no matter what `options[cc]` gives you, you're going to return `0` because that's the value of `out`.  Note that setting `out` in the various `fa`, `fb`, ... functions does *not* change the value of `out` in the caller.

You probably want:

```
def switchcase(num,cc):
    def fa(num):
        return num*1.1;
    def fb(num):
        return num*2.2;
    def fc(num):
        return num*3.3;
    def fd(num):
        return num*4.4;
    options = {
        "a":fa(num),
        "b":fb(num),
        "c":fc(num),
        "d":fd(num)
        } 
    return options[cc];
```

Also note that this will be horribly inefficient in practice.  You're creating 4 functions (and calling each) every time you call `switchcase`.

I'm guessing that you actually want to create a pre-made map of functions.  Then you can pick up the function that you actually want from the map and call it with the given number:

```
def fa(num):
    return num*1.1

def fb(num):
    return num*2.2

def fc(num):
    return num*3.3

def fd(num):
    return num*4.4

OPTIONS = {
    "a":fa,
    "b":fb,
    "c":fc,
    "d":fd
} 

def switchcase(num,cc):
    return OPTIONS[cc](num)
```

Comment: I'd add that now that `switchcase(num,cc)` does nothing but `options[cc](num)`, it might not be worth having that function at all.

Comment: @StefanPochmann -- That's reasonable.  There could be other functionality added though ... e.g. what if `cc` isn't in `options`?

Comment: Delicious: The individual functions are parameterised wn switchcase so that they are unevaluated unless required.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative take. You can just navigate to the necessary methods you have outside the switcher, and also pass optional arguments if you need:

```
def fa(num):
    return num*1.1
def fb(num):
    return num*2.2
def fc(num):
    return num*3.3
def fd(num, option=1):
    return num*4.4*option
def f_default(num):
    return num

def switchcase(cc):
    return {
        "a":fa,
        "b":fb,
        "c":fc,
        "d":fd,
    }.get(cc, f_default)

print switchcase("a")(10)  # for Python 3 --> print(switchcase("a")(10))
print switchcase("d")(10, 3)  # for Python 3 --> print(switchcase("d")(10, 3))
```

> print(switchcase("a")(10))
>
> 11.0
>
> print(switchcase("d")(10, 3))
>
> 132.0
>
> print(switchcase("ddd")(10))
>
> 10

Answer (score 0):

Another shorter version would be:

```py
def switchcase(num, cc):
    return {
        "a": lambda: num * 1.1,
        "b": lambda: num * 2.2,
        "c": lambda: num * 3.3,
        "d": lambda: num * 4.4,
        }.get(cc, lambda: None)()

print (switchcase(10,"a"))
```